# Get access to HKCR:\*\shell with Registry PSProvider

Tags: powershell

Can I somehow programmatically create a key inside *\shell key? It works fine when I do this manually, but in PS script it treats * as wildcard and tries to modify ALL keys.

Comment: `-LiteralPath HKCR:\*\shell`?

Comment: Thank you! (havt noticed it)